# como configurar o SMTP mailer no wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp

estou tentando configurar ele, mas esta dando o seguinte erro quando envio uma mensagem de test na aba Test Email.

```
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 

SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""

SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 closing connection u38-v6sm209121ywh.46 - gsmtp"

SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection u38-v6sm209121ywh.46 - gsmtp
Connection: closed

SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

esse e apenas o final do condigo.

Comment: da uma olhada http://wiki.integrator.com.br/index.php?title=Configurando_o_SMTP_do_Gmail_para_envio_de_aplicativos_online_em_servidores_da_Integrator

Answer (score 0):

Não há informação adicional sobre o servidor de SMTP mas assumindo que o "gsmtp" seja do Gmail, segue informação:

Por motivos de segurança, o Gmail bloqueia qualquer conexão de entrada para seu servidor SMTP. Para estabelecer uma conexão com o servidor SMTP do Gmail e enviar e-mails, você também precisará permitir aplicativos menos seguros em sua conta.

Se você não deseja ativar esse recurso, tente usar o plugin [Gmail SMTP](https://wphowto.net/gmail-smtp-plugin-for-wordpress-1341).

Fonte: https://wphowto.net/smtp-mailer-plugin-for-wordpress-1482